# Outlook 2016 emails to show unread after designated (assistant) reads them

Tags: microsoft-outlook

We have just switched over to Outlook 2016.  I am a designated (assistant) to my managers emails.  Unfortunately, when I read them - his emails show as read.  He would like them to show unread for himself until he reads them. How do we accomplish the task that it stays unread on his emails and read on mine for him?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you opening these messages in his inbox, or are you viewing a delegate mailbox? Have you tried changing the settings in File > Options >Mail > Reading Pane?

Answer (score 0):

The read status is synced to server side, so if this item is marked as read in one client and this client is connected to server, the status will be synced to other clients.

You may set an Outlook rule on the manager's mailbox, to forward his received email to you. Or ask your Exchange admin to setup a transport rule to send a copy of the email to you once your manager is the recipient or one of the recipients.